# Protractor Vs Suitest vs Cypress Which frame work is the better for large angular apps?

Tags: testing, automation, protractor, e2e-testing, cypress

What are the particular benefits or flaws Protractor has over [Suitest](https://suite.st/)
and Cypress ?
 1. Which would be better for multi-platform applications ?
 2. Will Suitest be suitable for large app?

Comment: What do you mean by `multi-platform` applications?

Comment: Running on different devices like Desktop, Xbox, TVs etc...

Answer (score 6):

I have used both Protractor and Cypress with Angular and non Angular apps. Protractor is suited for scenarios if you have to execute in multiple browsers like Chrome,FF- which is not possible in Cypress as of now- Cypress only supports Chrome and Electron as of now.

Since Protractor is just a wrapper or a sort-off port of Selenium webdriver, so it can do whatever the Webdriver can do, like working with multiple windows, frames etc, which are not available in windows.

Both are very different in architecture - one being a remote execution (protractor), while one being having native access (Cypress).

Cypress tests are bound to single origin, which is not in the case of Protractor.

**My Personal opinion** is too side with Protractor for large complex applications - because of the ease of working and my experience in working with WebDriver in general.

Haven't heard about Suitest before.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on what are you trying to achieve. If you need to make sure that your application is working in general, i.e. business logic is doing what you want - Protractor or Cypress would do the job for you in a web browser.

If you want to dig deeper and make sure your app runs fine on your target device - you should go with Suitest. It's a good way to test your app same way it's going to be used by the end user on TVs, Xbox etc. (anything other than web browser).

Disclaimer - I work at Suitest.